# TypeError: Cannot call method 'handle' of undefined

Tags: node.js, http, express

I want to create a simple http server using node js that will listen to a particular port . But I am facing with an error that looks like this :

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:123
  this._router.handle(req, res, function(err) {
               ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'handle' of undefined
    at Function.app.handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:123:16)
    at Server.app (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:28:9)
    at Manager.handleRequest (/home/node/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:565:28)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/node/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:119:10)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1966:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:527:27)
```

Below is the code I have written :

```
var express = require('express'); 
var http = require('http'); 

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(1200);
```

Recently only I have upgraded the node version and express as mentioned below :

express @ 4.4.1
node @ 0.10.28

Please can anyone explain where the error lies ?

Comment: you are not showing the whole code,since your error is related to socket.io

Comment: Yeah, by looking at the error again, indeed, the issue is socket.io related, as mentioned by @mpm yet your code does not inform about this.

Comment: For your information I have mentioned the full code above.

Comment: use a node.js debugger and turn-on the break on exception feature and when the error pops up examine the callstack and the variables - especially the one the should be defined but is not. What is your development OS?

Comment: This is NOT a socket.io issue. socket.io hijacks http requests automatically but is not reason. The reason is the lack of an explicit error message from express. This is fixed at least since express version 4.13.3.

Comment: This is fixed in express version 4.5.1. https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2773

Answer (score 0):

I assume this error comes when you point your browser to the server address and port, right?
In which case -from looking at your code- you are missing something like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(200, "All set");
});
```

Furthermore, there is no need for the `http` library:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(200, "All set");
});

app.listen(1200);
```

Should work. Please let me know.

And here is a working example with socket.io:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    socket = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.join('chatRoom');
    });

    socket.sockets.in('chatRoom').emit('message', 'Welcome in this room.');

    res.send(200, "All set");
});

app.listen(1200);
```

You still need to define the logic to intercept the emitted event on your client.

Comment: I am not pointing my browser to the server address and port; I am just running the above mentioned code in the terminal(putty).

Comment: That very code you posted is what you are running and you get that error? - It does not make any sense since there is a socket message in your error, yet no trace of sockets in your code. That code you posted works just fine.

Try running the examples I have posted and let me know what error you get then.

Comment: I didnt get your point in that you said there is no need for the http library. But still in the above example that you have written with socket io , you have used http library.

Comment: For socket.io you need it. You initial code -question- did not mention anything about socket, so my first code example / response was not taking socket.io into account.